# Question about the use of "in this spirit" expression

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

Is the use of "In this spirit" correct in the following context?

Marcel Proust wrote ``Let us be grateful to the people who make us happy; they are the charming gardeners who make our souls blossom". In this spirit, I would like to express my gratitude to all my fellow students.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. A variant is "It is in this spirit that I would ...".

Comment: The "spirit" refers to the essence of the sentiment or outlook conveyed by the preceding.